# Usage of "to double down" in British and American English

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english

The idiom "to double to on sth" in the sense of "continuing to do something in an even more determined way than before" is mentioned in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double-down-on-sth). However, personally, I've heard this exclusively in American English. Thus my question: is this phrase also commonly used in British English or rather just in American English? And if the latter is true, what would be a British equivalent?

Comment: I do hear it occasionally in England, but I think phrases like "get stuck into sth" are more common.

Comment: I've never heard "to double to" (in the US).  "Double down" is a gambling term and it means to be even more determined/bet more.

Comment: @HotLicks: That's one usage. The other one is also mentioned in the Merriam-Webster dictionary: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20down: "to become more tenacious, zealous, or resolute in a position or undertaking"

Comment: @royskatt - Yes, but that meaning derives from the concept of doubling your bet.

Comment: My dictionary says that "double down" comes from Blackjack (the player doubles his bet on seeing his initial cards).  So I am guessing the other uses evolved from this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no relevant instances of *double down* in the British National Corpus and 491 instances in the Corpus of Contemporary American English, so it seem likely that this phrase is not commonly used in British English.

Comment: It may be one of those expressions that's slowly creeping into British English; I think many Brits would understand it, at least vaguely, though it still sounds American. (I didn't know its origin, though — I assumed that it was probably from baseball or basketball…)

Comment: From poker or gambling more generally. The BNC is quite old by now, so the situation could certainly have changed.